# Kotlin data class with interface boilerplate

Tags: interface, kotlin, boilerplate, data-class

Data classes in Kotlin are great for eliminating much of the boilerplate of a Java pojo; but when a data class mirrors an interface, the two declarations still appear redundant. Take this example.

```
interface MyInterface {
    val foo: String
    val bar: String
    val baz: String
    val qux: String
}

data class MyImplementation(
    override val foo: String,
    override val bar: String,
    override val baz: String,
    override val qux: String
) : MyInterface
```

Is there any shorthand to eliminate this code duplication, i.e. to tell Kotlin that each `val` in the interface should be implemented by an identical `val` in the data class?

Comment: then what's the point of creating the interface in the first place. just use data class without the interface. am I missing something here?

Comment: I'd like to use the data class as a delegate.

Comment: Have you tried to use default implementations for your interface methods? Their usage is limited but maybe its sufficient for your case.

Comment: @jaco0646 you may want to show us what you are trying to accomplish with the delegate then. Even though there is no short-hand to eliminate that redundancy now, there might be something to at least improve the delegation.

Answer (score 2):

All properties in interfaces are abstract by default, so they have to be implemented (declared) by inheritors. According to  [this links](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/default-property-initialization-for-interfaces/249), this feature was not planned in 2015, and it looks like it's still not implemented.